# How to pass the yml file and an extra argument to a playbook.yml file?

Tags: ansible

I have a bash script from which `playbook.yml` is called as follows:

```
 ANSIBLE_FORCE_COLOR=true ansible-playbook -e 'host_key_checking=False' /vagrant/playbook.yml --extra-vars "@/vagrant/config.yml target=$server_name" -vvvv
```

Hence as it can be seen in the above line that `--extra-vars "@/vagrant/config.yml target=$server_name"` is mentioned and it contains one `config.yml` which is another yml file and another is the argument as `target=$server_name`. Now the problem is that its throwing error as above also config.yml is at the correct place and if the `playbook.yml` is called with just one variable like as follows it is works properly:

```
ANSIBLE_FORCE_COLOR=true ansible-playbook -e 'host_key_checking=False' /vagrant/playbook.yml --extra-vars "@/vagrant/config.yml" -vvvv
```

So please suggest how can I pass the two variables to the `playbook.yml` so that it gets executed well.

Answer (score 1):

Just repeat the `--extra-vars` parameter. In the same way as you have defined `host_key_checking` (`-e` is synonymous with `--extra-vars`):

```
ANSIBLE_FORCE_COLOR=true ansible-playbook playbook.yml -e "host_key_checking=False target=$server_name" -e "@/vagrant/config.yml" -vvvv
```

Answer (score 0):

extra vars can be loaded from a yml file with the `@` syntax:

```
ANSIBLE_FORCE_COLOR=true ansible-playbook playbook.yml -e "host_key_checking=False target=$server_name" -e@/vagrant/config.yml -vvvv
```

Comment: I'm really sorry, but how does it differ from [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41973114/2947502)? Not to mention that OP already knew they could do it and specified a different problem.

Comment: that the minor difference: with the @ syntax

Comment: And what implications does this minor difference have?